# Porque pode estar causando erro na hora de comparar duas datas no php

Tags: php

tenho a seguinte linha de codigo:

```
if($dataexpira < $dataLocal){ echo "Expirou data!";}
```

o Que nelas esta armazenado as seguintes strings:

```
if("04/02/2019 18:18:48" < "16/01/2019 18:18:48"){echo "Expirou data!"}
```

porem ele ao comparar dessa forma, ele entende como data Expirada, **pois esta comparando se é maior o dia** e **" nao seu todo"**...

como comparar seu todo...

Comment: Use a classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php). Comparar *string* só vai funcionar se tiver no formato `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: Desculpe minha pergunta, mas eu consigo utilizar essas strings para transformar em DateTime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto forma abaixo irá transformar sua string em um objeto de datas, e assim você fará as comparações com mais segurança, comparando representações numéricas como timestamp.

```
<?php
// Objeto que representa a data expira.
$DataExpira = new DateTime();
$DataExpira->setTimestamp(strtotime("2019-02-16 18:18:48"));
// Objeto que representa a data local.
$DataLocal = new DateTime();
$DataLocal->setTimestamp(strtotime("2019-02-16 18:18:48"));
// Saí apenas para teste.
print "1 :: dataexpira :: " . $DataLocal->getTimestamp();
print "<br>";
print "2 :: dataLocal :: " . $DataExpira->getTimestamp();
print "<br>";
// Teste de datas.
if ($DataExpira->getTimestamp() < $DataLocal->getTimestamp()) {
    echo "Expirou data!";
} else {
    echo "NÃO Expirou data!";
}
?>
```

Fazendo assim ficará melhor a sua representação de datas.

Comment: Perfeito amigo ... isso ajudou muito !!!! obrigado....

Comment: Se no final você vai comparar o *timestamp*, nem precisa usar a classe `DateTime`, a função `strtotime` já retorna o valor, basta usá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa fazer tudo isso que foi apresentado na outra resposta. Se fosse para comparar os *timestamps* apenas nem precisaria utilizar a classe `DateTime`.

```
$expira = strtotime("2019-02-16 18:18:48");
$local = strtotime("2019-02-16 18:18:48");

if ($expira < $local) {
    ...
}
```

Mas veja que o formato da data mudou nesse caso, pois a função `strtotime` não reconhece o padrão que você possui.

Se deseja usar `DateTime`, como o formato `"16/01/2019 18:18:48"` não é um formato reconhecido internacionalmente, você precisa especificar como a classe `DateTime` irá processar o valor informado; faça isso com o método `DateTime::createFromFormat`:

```
$expira = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "04/02/2019 18:18:48");
$local = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "16/01/2019 18:18:48");
```

Perceba que definimos o formato como `"d/m/Y H:i:s"` para o PHP saber o que é cada número. Neste caso, o formato é `<dia>/<mês>/<ano com 4 dígitos> <hora no formato 24h>/<minutos>/<segundos>`. O método é estático e retorna uma nova instância de `DateTime`.

Como `DateTime` é nativo do PHP (e escrito em C), ela possui a sobrecarga de operadores implementada. Isto é, você pode comparar dois objetos `DateTime` com os operadores `>`, `<`, etc, normalmente. Portanto, para saber se `$expira` é menor que `$local`, basta fazer:

```
if ($expira < $local) {

}
```

Assim, ficando:

```
$expira = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "04/02/2019 18:18:48");
$local = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "16/01/2019 18:18:48");

if ($expira < $local) {
    ...
}
```